# Spark receiving Data from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am really new to Spark and Kafka, so I wondered, if there is an easy method to
"***read***" so to say a kafka topic with sparkstreaming in java.
All I could find to this was, that i have to create an `JavaInputDstream` *that subscribes to a certain topic*. I did that and tried to test a few functions of the Inputstream, like `count()`, `print()`, etc. but nothing really happend. I would appreciate it if somebody could help me out, thanks :)

My code is as follows:

```
public class kafkaConnection2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String URL = "spark://XXXXXXXXX";


    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-test").setMaster(URL);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(5));


    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "XXXXXXXX");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "ID1");

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("MAX_LEGO");

     JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));     



    stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
    stream.count();
    stream.map()
    ssc.start();



 try {
        ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("smth went terribly wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```